# tabbed activity not showing any tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, tabbed

If I try and create a new project with a tabbed activity, no tabs show.  Call me crazy, but I'd actually like tabs on my "tabbed activity".  I searched on Youtube and it seems tabs just come up for others.  Did something change with the newest version of Android studio?  How do I add actual tabs and where do I edit the contents of the 3 fragments I want?  This seems more confusing than it needs to be.  Thanks.

Comment: Post some code to show us what you've done.

Comment: I haven't done anything.  I just tried to add a new tabbed activity.

Comment: please add more info, code or examples

Comment: If I start a new project and create a tabbed activity no tabs show.  I don't know what code you want me to show.  Android Studio is doing everything.  If I try posting the default code stackoverflow says it's too long.

Comment: Just post the XML Layout of the "tabbed" activity. You will find this xml file in your "/res/layout" folder.

Comment: Nevermind...my bad.  On the Android Studio versions on Youtube there's an option for using tabs that just comes up on the screen while creating a new tabbed activity.  Mine had a scrollbar that I didn't see so I just had to scroll down further.  User error.  :)

Comment: @Matt, u can put that down as your accepted answer. This helped me!